# Запуск апплета внутри приложения C#

Tags: java, c#

День добрый. Есть Java-апплет, а именно игра Minecraft.

Запускается она таким методом:

```
java -Xmx1024m -Djava.library.path=natives -cp "minecraft.jar;jinput.jar;lwjgl.jar;lwjgl_util.jar;" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "ИМЯ" "СЕКРЕТНАЯ_СЕССИЯ"
```

Проблема в том, что после запуска, в любом процесс-менеджере можно увидеть строку запуска и увидеть секретную сессию.
А это совсем недопустимо.

Подскажите, как запустить его и "захандлить" так, что бы процесс java.exe виден был, но вот параметры -- нет.

---

**UPD. Может есть способ открыть Minecraft при помощи JNI?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо поменять содержимое поля CommandLine структуры [RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa813741(VS.85).aspx), которая находится в структуре [PEB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa813706(VS.85).aspx) необходимого процесса.

Получить адрес этой структуры можно получить например используя функцию [NtQueryInformationProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), указав ей в качестве аргумента `ProcessInformationClass` значение `ProcessBasicInformation`.

Об этом довольно много написано на англоязычном SO - например, [вот в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3992953/860331).

Для того, что бы изменить PEB другого процесса, вам придется использовать [WriteProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Простых методов "в одну строчку" для этого в C# нет - вам придется либо самому переносить определение необходимых структур и функций WinApi, либо копировать их с [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Любой пользователь с правами администратора в системе будет видеть параметры командной строки любого процесса.

Comment: Как странно. Однако я видел, что это было реализовано. Вы уверены?

Comment: Более чем. Может быть было организовано через временный файл-конфиг, который удалялся после старта. Но это должно поддерживаться самим приложением. Ну и к тому же пользователь всегда может взять дебаггер, прицепиться к приложению java и просто посмотреть значения в отладке.

Comment: Дебаггер подключить не получится. На процессе защита от него.
А что на счет JNI? Можно ли через него попытаться запустить Java-приложение?

Comment: Где-то я уже видел этот вопрос и там было какое-то шаманство с затиранием командной строки после запуска...

Comment: Защита от дебаггера на вызов java? Да просто подмена java.exe на фейковый это обходит. Защита от отладчика обходится дампом памяти и спокойным ковырянием стека и кучи в поисках параметра.

Comment: Java проверяется на валидность.

Comment: @AGrief ветка реестра image file execution options позволяет подменить запуск любого exe-файла, стандартными средствами. т.е. при прямом запуске полностью валидного java.exe есть возможность запустить не java, а вообще все что угодно. Не верите - выложите свой лаунчер для майнкрафта в открытый доступ - и посмотрите как быстро из него достанут ваш секретный ключ.

Comment: MD5 самого процесса+библиотек проверяются и сверяются. Какая разница через что он запущен? Исполняемый файл (именно через который он запущен) будет проверятся на валидность. Если он подменен - вуаля, или я ошибаюсь в чем-то?

Comment: @PashaPash
PS. Почему-бы не чекать эту ветку Image File Execution? :)

Comment: @AGrief вы проверяете MD5 процесса и библиотек - значит вы делаете это уже после запуска. Когда параметр уже ушел кому нужно. Чекайте ветку. но даже тривиальный java.com обойдет вашу "защиту"  (com запускается до exe, а вы не указали расширение). Да и набор библиотек будет разный на разных платформах (очень разный, все не проверите). Строчка появляется в открытом виде на клиенте - значит ее можно перехватить. Тем более, если вы ее пытаетесь передать через известное место (брекпойнт на Create Process). То, что вы делаете - это security through obscurity, оно еще никого ни от чего не защищало :)

Comment: @PashaPash, почему-бы не сделать это до запуска и не проверять через определенный интервал времени? Человека задолбит доставать каждый раз сессию что бы зайти.

Comment: @AGrief не совсем понял что сделать до запуска, но тем не менее - я вообще не понимаю зачем вы прячете сессию от конечного пользователя, если она все равно каждый раз разная. Если одинаковая - то зачем человеку ее каждый раз доставать?

Comment: Что бы не запилили мультиобход автоматический.

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не запустить своё приложение на Java, которое [загрузит и запустит нужный jar внутри процесса](http://www.coderanch.com/t/529764/java/java/run-jar-java-application)? Это должно решить проблему.

Comment: Это не даёт защиты от отладки. Я сомневаюсь что её вообще можно достичь, если учесть что строка появляется на стороне "злоумышленника" в открытом виде дважды - в C# и в java.

Comment: @PashaPash: Полной защиты от отладки не даёт ничего, если целевое приложение запускается под контролем атакующего. Нативный код прекрасно взламывается, ну только квалификация должна быть чуть повыше.

Comment: Этому приложению тоже будет передаваться логин и сессия..

Comment: @AGrief: Зачем же, там можно захардкодировать.

Comment: @VladD приложение на java - сторон неё, насколько я понял. Есть готовый jar, его нельзя поменять. И этот jar ждёт параметров в открытом виде.

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну, мы загружаем этот сторонний jar, и вызываем в нём функцию `main`. И передаём ей параметры, которые у нас захардкодированы в «настоящем» `main`.

Comment: @vlad потом берем отладчик и спокойно достаем параметры `main` стороннего jar из стека. в случае с C# это буквально в два клика делается - windbg -> sos -> !dso. В java наверняка есть аналог.

Comment: @PashaPash: Так против юзера с отладчиком ничего не спасает. Даже нативный код.

Comment: @VladD да, поэтому попытки TC защитить секретный ключ от end user заведомо обречены на провал

Comment: @PashaPash, код можно обфусцировать. И очень хорошо запутать логику.